# Is it possible to recoverDB File in sybase? i have lost my db file

Tags: sybase-asa

I have lost my "Trak.db" there is log file is available is it possible to recover this one through log file? use of Log files?

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to run DBTran against the log file and it will generate a SQL file for the statements that were executed while that log was running.  Of course, whether or not the log will contain all your data is going to be based on how you were logging/truncating/backing up.  Technically it is possible if you have all your logs and the schema.

For reference: http://www.ianywhere.com/developer/product_manuals/sqlanywhere/0901/en/html/dbdaen9/00000590.htm